# Bundle custom library using webpack and lodash as dependency

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, lodash

I need help here.
I am bundling a custom library (named for the example *LibraryJS* and it uses lodash as dependency.

In the webpack configuration I setup lodash as an external dependency like so:

```
{
   externals: {
       "lodash"
   }
}
```

It works great.
But then when I want to use this library inside another project, I got the following error: "*libraryjs.js:77 Uncaught ReferenceError: lodash is not defined*"

which is the following line:

```
/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

=> module.exports = lodash;

/***/ }),
```

The fact is, I am using lodash as well in my project, so it should be working.
What am I doing wrong?

By the way, I am using gulp + browserify to bundle my project and gulp + gulp-webpack to bundle the library.

Edit: I found a way to fix the error, but I really don't want to stick with this fix because it's really... ugly... See bellow:

```
const lodash = require('lodash')
window.lodash = lodash; // <= The fix, ugh
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had a similar situation trying to build a library - this is the solution I found.

**Goal:**
Build a library that depends on Lodash without including Lodash in that library bundle.
The consumer of the library is responsible for making Lodash available to our library.

I used the [Authoring Libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/) section of the documentation to put together this solution.

Specifically these two sections:

- [Externalize Lodash](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#externalize-lodash)
- [Expose the Library](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#expose-the-library)

There is an example project showing this configuration as well:
https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/externals

---

## Solution:

### 1. Bundle our library, excluding lodash

```
// "my-lib" package.json
{
    "name": "my-lib",
    "version": "0.5.0",
    "main": "my-lib.js",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "lodash": "^4.17.5"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
    }
}
```

Here's our example library that imports lodash and uses it. Note that whilst we depend on lodash, it won't be included in our bundle.

```
// lib-entry.js
import _ from "lodash";

export default function doubleUp(listOfNum){
    // Do something using lodash
    let result = _.flatMap(listOfNum, (i) => [i, i]);
    return result;
}
```

Here's our `webpack.config.js` that bundles our library, but excludes lodash from the bundle:

```
// "my-lib" webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'my-lib': './lib-entry.ts', 
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',

        // [1]
        libraryTarget: 'umd',

        /*
        [2]
        NOTE: until this issue is fixed: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6525
        we need to define `globalObject` in Webpack 4 to correctly build a universal library
        (i.e. node and browser compatible).
        */
        globalObject: 'this',
    },
    externals: {
        // [3]
        'lodash': {
            commonjs: 'lodash',
            commonjs2: 'lodash',
            amd: 'lodash',
            root: '_',
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
};
```

[1] This tells Webpack to bundle our library for different environments (so it will work when loaded via: browser scripts, Node CommonJS, AMD, and downstream Webpack projects). NOTE: This is needed otherwise the `externals` config in [3] will output an incorrect `undefined` module in your bundle.

[2] Workaround for a Webpack 4 bug (if you're in the future then check if this is still relevant and needed). Also described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119917/81723

[3] From the documentation: "set the `externals` option to define dependencies that should be resolved in the target environment". We're telling Webpack to exclude lodash from the library bundle and that consumers of our library are responsible for providing it.

### 2. Use the library in a downstream application

Define an application that depends on our `my-lib` library:

```
// "my-app" package.json
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "dependencies": {
        "lodash": "^4.17.5",
        "my-lib": "^0.5.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.5.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^2.0.14"
    }
}
```

Our application imports lodash into its environment (because our library needs it) and then use our library:

```
// app-entry.js
import _ from "lodash";
import doubleUp from "my-lib";

let result = doubleUp([1, 2, 3]);
console.log(result);    // [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

Here's the `webpack.config.js` for our application:

```
// "my-app" webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'my-app': './app-entry.ts', 
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
        alias: {
            /*
            [1]
            Resolve all `lodash` requests to the same location otherwise
            we end up with two versions loaded into the bundle, one
            for `my-lib` and one for `my-app`.
            */
            lodash: path.resolve('./node_modules/lodash/index.js'),
        }
    },
};
```

[1] This `alias` config means anytime Webpack encounters `require('lodash')` or `import ... from "lodash";` it will resolve it to this one module on disk. I found I had to do this to avoid getting multiple versions of lodash loaded into my bundle. Webpack was including one version for `my-app` and one for `my-lib`, but this fixes it so that both get the same version.

Comment: lodash should be a `peerDependency`, not a `devDependency`, since it is needed at runtime but not bundled with OP's library.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated. Wasn't sure if `peerDependencies` were installed locally in the library project (e.g. for testing) but it looks like they are.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Answer is late, but it still interesting to read about !

Comment: @DanO you should *always* include peerDependencies in devDependencies for testing purposes. If not, when you're testing a module that requires lodash it'll fail bc lodash does not exist.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal, thx for the well-explained answer, but if i simply put `_: 'lodash'` or ` 'lodash': _` in `externals` section i it works without any error. Any explanation ?

Comment: @cizario The `lodash: '_'` string version relies on the existence of a global `_` variable. [The externals docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#object) say "[the object] syntax is used to describe all the possible ways that an external library can be made available" to a umd library project - so it offers more explicit control of where the external comes from and doesn't necessarily rely on globals. Generally it's best to avoid globals, if possible, but it depends on the specific environment you're authoring for.