# Webpack 4 universal library target

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundler, umd, webpack-4

According to the [Webpack 4 documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-librarytarget), if I specify **libraryTarget: 'umd'** it should result in the following output:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
  if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory();
  else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define([], factory);
  else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["MyLibrary"] = factory();
  else
    root["MyLibrary"] = factory();
})(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this, function() {
  return _entry_return_;
});
```

However, what I get is:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define("lib", [], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["lib"] = factory();
    else
        root["lib"] = factory();
})(window, function() {
return
```

To be more precise, instead of this
`(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this, function()`
I get this:
`(window, function()`

This (obviously) causes runtime error `window is undefined` when importing in node environment.

**To be clear:**
I know that `window` doesn't exist in node applications. My question is not about this, but rather about **webpack**.

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

My output config:

```
output: {
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'umd'),
    filename: 'lib.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'lib',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
},
```

Comment: What target do you have set: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

Comment: The default. But it doesn't matter. `libraryTarget: 'umd'` should produce universal code (works both in browser and node). This is according to their documentation: "libraryTarget: "umd" - This exposes your library under all the module definitions, allowing it to work with CommonJS, AMD and as global variable." Also, I built the exact same code with **Webpack 3** and it produced a proper bundle. Bottom line - this is a bug in **Webpack 4** just as I stated in my answer.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This would be a [bug](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6677) in **Webpack 4**.
**Webpack 3** produces a proper bundle.

This issue should be fixed with [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6525) feature, until it's done the suggested workaround is using `globalObject`:

```
output: {
    path: resolve(__dirname, 'umd'),
    filename: 'lib.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library: 'lib',
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    globalObject: `(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this)`
},
```

Answer (score 6):

According to the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputglobalobject) include `output.globalObject` into **webpack.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    globalObject: 'this'
  }
}
```

*To make UMD build available on both browsers and Node.js, set output.globalObject option to 'this'.*