# Dynamic imports stopped working in Webpack v4

Tags: webpack, babeljs, dynamic-import

There is a lot of questions like this one ([for example this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976936/how-to-get-dynamic-imports-to-work-in-webpack-4)), and everyone says that the solution is just to install `babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import`.

But, in my case, I have it already installed. I had webpack@3 before, and it worked. 
Now I'm upgrading to v4; just installed new version of webpack – and dynamic imports does not work anymore.

```
ERROR in ./layouts/ClassList/index.js 89:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (89:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| var Component = (0, _decorators.asChunk)(function () {
>   return import( /* webpackChunkName: "ClassList" */"./Component");
| });
```

How is it possible? And how to make work again?